# PWM npn sinking signal

Tags: pic, motor, pwm, stepper-motor

I have a stepper motor(with [STR2 Step Motor Drive](http://www.applied-motion.com/products/stepper-drives/str2)) which needs npn sinking signal to operate. [dsPIC33EP512mu810](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en554307) is capable of generating high resolution pwm. However, the PWM signal can only turn on a LED but not the motor.

It works if I manully switch a pin on and off with some delay to operate the motor.
I've searched through data sheet and app notes but PWM output type is not mentioned. Any suggestion on PWM signal type and how to convert PWM into npn sinking signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 208 shows the block diagram of a typical I/O port.

[image]

The PWM peripheral communicates with the output drivers via the output multiplexers. Therefore the sink/source capabilities in PWM mode are the same as when they're in GPIO mode, which for this device is either 15mA or 20mA.

You may need to use an external driver fed from the PWM signal if you need strong sinking and sourcing capabilities.